# cocoa: in NSWebView, Click on the hyperlink trigger, Is there any way

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, uiwebview

`– webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`In web view Click on the hyperlink trigger ，Is there any way How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
//WebView will automatically load the hyperlink u need not to do anything out there except.
//Inherit <UIWebViewDelegate> in self;
urwebview.delegate=self;
In self implement delegate method 
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    //Its call back receved whenever ur webview is navigated By clicking on hyperlink
}
```

Comment: I was in the development of Mac applications .

Comment: NSWebView  and UIWebView Usage of the same ?

Comment: Yeah,In Mac Appkit its NSWebView,In ios UIKit its UIWebView